# Move past commits to their own branch

Tags: git

I have a git repo that looks kinda like this:

```
   A - B - C - D - E - F
   ^                   ^
   |                   |
Staging              master
```

I want to move the Staging branch pointer to E, but I don't want commits B and D to be in the branch.  I want to put B and D into their own branch.

```
            Staging
               |
               V
A ---- C ----- E - F <- master
  \               /
   B ----- D -----
           ^
           |
         new branch
```

I have no idea how to move the commits out of the master branch chain and move them to their own branch, and then re-merge them into master again.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Side note on the two forms of answer (interactive rebase, vs cherry-pick): the `git rebase -i` operation is done by a shell script and actually works by doing cherry-picks (with additional code for squash, fixup, etc, and optimizations).

Comment: @torek: Neat.  Did not know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [interactive rebasing](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_interactive_mode) (`git rebase -i`) for these kind of transformations.

1. Create `new-branch`

   ```
   git checkout -b new-branch D
   git rebase -i A^
   ```
2. Move `staging`:

   ```
   git checkout staging
   git reset --hard E
   git rebase -i A^
   ```
3. Update `master`:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git reset --hard staging
   git merge new-branch
   ```

**Interactive rebasing**

You start the interactive rebasing with `git rebase -i A^` (which takes everything from `HEAD` to `A`). Your editor will open and present the commit ordered from oldest to newest (beware, this is dhe opposite order of `git log` and confusing sometimes). You can rearrange commits by rearranging the corresponding lines. You can also delete lines, which deletes the associated commits. (In your case deleting should be sufficient.)

*Note: Rebasing changes the history which you should not do, if you have already published your history to your colleagues.*

Comment: I can try re-basing.  I'm currently the only developer with a checked out repo.

Comment: Woo!  This allowed to do exactly what I wanted! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Create two new branches based on A:

```
git branch staging-new A
git branch new-branch A
```

Then use cherry-picking to pick the commits you want for each branch:

```
git checkout staging-new
git cherry-pick C E
```

and similar for new-branch.

Then you can delete the old branch Staging. master remains untouched.

Notes:

- This will be more complicated if any of the intermediate commits are merge commits (because cherry-picking a merge commmit is more complex).
- Since you are recreating branch Staging, any branches based on it (by you or others) will have to be changed (typically rebased).
- You will not get exactly what you describe, because cherry-picking creates new commits. So staging-new and new-branch will *not* be ancestors of master (as in your picture). To obtain that, you will have to modify master's history using rebase. Of course this is usually only advisable if you have not yet shared master.

Comment: This looks like it could work, and may be simpler than rebasing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works (if I may say so) :-). It is simpler than rebasing, but also does less: To get master in the stat as described in your question, you must rebase.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how I wanted the repo to look like, because I wasn't sure what options I had.  I may just rebase, just to see what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `git cherry-pick` to selectively move commits from one branch to another.

This article may help you: http://technosophos.com/content/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches

And from the git manual: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick